# Who handles request if posting from an iframe?

Tags: javascript, html, iframe, iframe-app

Let save I have an parent page that I control. Inside this parent page, I place an iframe. The src of the iframe is on a different domain.

When I submit a form from the Iframe, who handles the request? The web app of the parent page or web app of the iframe?

I think the request goes to the iframe's web app, by I'm not sure?

Comment: it is "handled" by whoever is specified in the form's action

Comment: Almost everything done in the iframe stays stays there. You have very little control over what happens inside of there. This is in part to prevent fishing sites that use iframes to trick users.